# how to include custom methods in Custom observer magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have a custom observer with different method definitions:

1. Should the observer include only execute method?
2. If i can include all the methods, how?

`Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncObserver.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SyncObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
 protected $_queue;

/**
 * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory
 */
protected $syncQueueFactory;

/**
 * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;

function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory $syncQueueFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
)
{
    $this->syncQueueFactory = $syncQueueFactory;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_queue = $this->syncQueueFactory->create();
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    //echo 'Sync obssrexe';die;
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    //$this->tglssearchEngineFactory->getCatlogSearchResult();
}

//How to include these methods here... if i just put it here, they are no getting called

public function method1(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{...}

public function method2(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{...}
```

**UPDATED**

Can i use something like this?

```
function __construct(
    \Vendor\module\Model\QueueFactory $syncQueueFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
)
{
    $this->syncQueueFactory = $syncQueueFactory;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_queue = $this->syncQueueFactory->create();
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    //echo 'Sync obssrexe';die;
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $this->syncQueueFactory->productUpdate();
}
```

My QueueFactory:

```
public function productUpdate(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{...}
```

Comment: Yes you can use syncQueueFactory

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the other methods?
If you need to call them just inside your `execute` method you should make them `protected`.
If you are planning to use them outside the class also, maybe you need to rethink your architecture.
The scope of an observer is to so something when a certain event is dispatched.
If you want it to do something else, you are breaking the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
In this case you may want to move your other methods in an other class.

Comment: Can i use like above,i updated the answer

Comment: I see that the method `productUpdate` expects a parameter. You can call it in your observer like this  `$this->syncQueueFactory->productUpdate($this);` but maybe you should change the parameter type from `\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer` to `\Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface`

Comment: what if there multiple methods in QueueFactory?, how to call it in observer using syncQueueFactory

Comment: You lost me here. Maybe you should explain in the question what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Im just trying to add the product id to my custom table when any change is made to the product :P